# Installing OpenAL using vcpkg but encounters error

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I'm trying to install OpenAL using vcpkg tools, but it gave an error message that I can not resolve.
Error message is as below.

> C:\Dev\vcpkg\vcpkg-2021.05.12>vcpkg install openal-soft:x64-windows
> Computing installation plan...
> The following packages will be built and installed:
> openal-soft[core]:x64-windows -> 1.21.1
> Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
> -- Setting HTTP_PROXY environment variables to http://127.0.0.1:16005
> -- Setting HTTPS_PROXY environment variables to https://127.0.0.1:16005
> -- Setting SOCKS_PROXY environment variables to socks://127.0.0.1:16005
> Error: while detecting compiler information:
> The log content at C:\Dev\vcpkg\vcpkg-2021.05.12\buildtrees\detect_compiler\stdout-x64-windows.log is:
> -- Found ninja('1.8.2') but at least version 1.10.1 is required! Trying to use internal version if possible!
> -- Downloading https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases/download/v1.10.1/ninja-win.zip -> ninja-win-1.10.1.zip...
> -- Downloading https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases/download/v1.10.1/ninja-win.zip... Failed. Status: 4;"A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision."
> CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_download_distfile.cmake:184
> (message):
>
> ```
>   Failed to download file.
>   If you use a proxy, please set the HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY environment
>   variables to "https://user:password@your-proxy-ip-address:port/".
>
>   If error with status 4 (Issue #15434),
>   try setting "http://user:password@your-proxy-ip-address:port/".
>
>   Otherwise, please submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues
> ```
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> scripts/cmake/vcpkg_find_acquire_program.cmake:544
> (vcpkg_download_distfile)
> scripts/cmake/vcpkg_configure_cmake.cmake:168
> (vcpkg_find_acquire_program)
> scripts/detect_compiler/portfile.cmake:18 (vcpkg_configure_cmake)
> scripts/ports.cmake:142 (include)
>
> Error: vcpkg was unable to detect the active compiler's information.
> See above for the CMake failure output.

What do I do about it?